# Android, SQL Exception: Before Result Set, code 0

Tags: android, sql, jdbc, sqlexception

I had a SQLException, with error message "Before result set" and code:0.

Usually those Exceptions happens trying to use a data from result set when it still is on the "0" position.

But i checked the code and this doesn't happen.

The query runs all right and the statement is ok.

```
     //array is an ArrayList<String>
     //statement is a Statement
     //rs is a ResultSet
     //connection is a Connection

        for(int i=0; i<array.size(); i++)
    {
        sql="SELECT PHONE "
                + "FROM MEMBERS"
                + " WHERE NAME='" + array.get(i) +"' "
                + " AND ADDRESS='" + address+"'";

        statement=connection.createStatement();

       rs=statement.executeQuery(sql);

        if(!rs.next())
        {
            MyException myException = new MyException("Operation not completed");
            throw myException;
        }
        statement.close();
        rs.close();
    }
```

logcat:

```
     05-25 00:23:54.696: W/System.err(18135): java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
     05-25 00:23:54.701: W/System.err(18135):   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
     05-25 00:23:54.701: W/System.err(18135):   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937)
     05-25 00:23:54.706: W/System.err(18135):   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
     05-25 00:23:54.706: W/System.err(18135):   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:872)
     05-25 00:23:54.706: W/System.err(18135):   at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:787)
     05-25 00:23:54.706: W/System.err(18135):   at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2460)
     05-25 00:23:54.711: W/System.err(18135):   at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2571)
     05-25 00:23:54.711: W/System.err(18135):   at com.example.organization.CreateObject$CreateObjectSubmitHandler.doInBackground(CreateObject.java:234)
     05-25 00:23:54.711: W/System.err(18135):   at com.example.organization.CreateObject$CreateObjectSubmitHandler.doInBackground(CreateObject.java:1)
     05-25 00:23:54.716: W/System.err(18135):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
     05-25 00:23:54.716: W/System.err(18135):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
     05-25 00:23:54.721: W/System.err(18135):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
     05-25 00:23:54.721: W/System.err(18135):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
     05-25 00:23:54.721: W/System.err(18135):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
     05-25 00:23:54.721: W/System.err(18135):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
     05-25 00:23:54.721: W/System.err(18135):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Please post your logcat showing the exception

Comment: Here it is the logcat

Comment: Now post `CreateObject` code and put some comment showing what line is line 234

Comment: Man, you got it! It wasn't the line that the logcat showed first, but the line 234! Thanks a lot, i think that after 8-9 hours straight of programming, one error is tolerable. Now i finished my work. Thanks.

Comment: I have just read the stacktrace. But glad it did help

Comment: All the time that errors happened i had only to check the logcat to find the line supposed to cause the fault. This is the first time that the fault is on another line, i didn't check it out.